# Microsoft Web Services Extension 3: Custom UsernameTokenManager does not throw error if password is missing in SOAP Request

Tags: web-services, authentication, wse, wse3.0

I am fairly familiar with how custom `UsernameTokenManager` works. It's all fine if a username & password is provided by the client in the SOAP request. If the client explicitly excludes the password (`<wsse:Password>` tag), I would expect the framework to throw a corresponding exception. Unfortunately the webservice call proceeds as usual. When debugging, I can see that my custom `UsernameTokenManager` is being invoked (method `AuthenticateToken`) and it returns the correct password; but something is not working after that. Any clues?